# Alternative for sed ... <(cmd) and cmd | sed

Tags: bash, sed, pipe

I want to set a command as configuration option of a program.
There are parameters passed to the command.

But I want the output of the command to be replaced with sed.

In principle I want to to do something like this:

```
option = cmd <arg1> <arg2> | sed s/x/y/
```

But the the option can only set this way:

```
 option = cmd
```

and the arguments are automatically append by the program.

So I want to "reverse" the pipe like this:

```
 option = sed s/x/y/ < <(cmd)
```

But since the program appends the arguments the following would
be exectuted:

```
 sed s/x/y/ < <(cmd) <arg1> <arg2>
```

but I wanted

```
 sed s/x/y/ < <(cmd <arg1> <arg2>)
```

Since there are no placeholders in the option for the arguments I am not able to close the parenthese properly.

Is there any way around this without writing a wrapper script?

Comment: What if you do `option = "cmd arg1 args2"`? Maybe this way everything will be put inside the `<(part)`

Comment: no, I only talked about arg1 and arg2 to tell my intention. the program automatically appends whatever arg1 and arg2 is to the end to the option command. The solution below is perfect - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're careful with quoting, you can do it like this:

```
option = bash -c 'cmd "$1" "$2" | sed "s/x/y/"' sub
```

The word "sub" at the end is arbitrary but necessary; it's there because `$1` in the subshell created with `bash -c` is actually the second positional argument, not the first one.

Comment: +1 As a matter of personal preference, I like to use `_` where you used `sub`. You'll see it a lot in commands like `find . … -exec sh -c 'do stuff "$@"' _ {} +`

Comment: @kojiro: I also often use that (or -), but it's too easy to ignore in an example, and many cargoculters seem to believe that it is somehow special syntax, so I try to avoid it in explanations.

Comment: I needed \s in the original sed, so I went with
`bash -c 'cmd "$1" "$2" | sed "s/^\\+\\+\\+\\\\s/+++/"' _`
thanks!

Comment: @metakeule: If you're using GNU sed, you should be able to write that without backslashes as `sed -r "s/^[+]{3}[[:space:]]/+++/". Whether that's more readable or not is totally personal.